# Annotating instance properties which are set by constructor parameters?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

When using the google closure compiler, is it necessary to annotate properties that are set by constructor parameters?  e.g.

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} bar
 * @param {number} barPrivate
 */
var Foo = function(bar, barPrivate) {
  this.bar = bar;
  this.barPrivate_ = barPrivate;
};
```

If I write this, is the compiler smart enough to figure out that:

1. the `bar` property has type `{string}`?
2. the `barPrivate` property has type `{number}`?
3. the `barPrivate` property is `@private`?

Or do I need to be more explicit?

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} bar
 * @param {number} barPrivate
 */
var Foo = function(bar, barPrivate) {
  /** @type {string} */
  this.bar = bar;
  /** @private {number} */
  this.barPrivate_ = barPrivate;
};
```

The latter form seems to be less "DRY", but it's what we've been using  to be on the safe side.  I haven't found any documentation on this either way...

After doing some minimal exploration the [AST with visibility declarations (but no type declarations)](http://closure-compiler-debugger.appspot.com/#input0%3D%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540constructor%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Bstring%257D%2520bar%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Bnumber%257D%2520barPrivate%250A%2520*%252F%250Avar%2520Foo%2520%253D%2520function(bar%252C%2520barPrivate)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%252F**%2520%2540public%2520*%252F%250A%2520%2520this.bar%2520%253D%2520bar%253B%250A%2520%2520%252F**%2520%2540private%2520*%252F%250A%2520%2520this.barPrivate_%2520%253D%2520barPrivate%253B%250A%257D%26input1%26conformanceConfig%26externs%26refasterjs-template%26includeDefaultExterns%3D1%26CHECK_SYMBOLS%3D1%26CHECK_TYPES%3D1%26CHECK_VISIBILITY%3D1%26CLOSURE_PASS%3D1%26LANG_IN_IS_ES6%3D1%26MISSING_PROPERTIES%3D1%26PRESERVE_TYPE_ANNOTATIONS%3D1%26PRETTY_PRINT%3D1%26TRANSPILE%3D1)
is the same as the 
[AST when type declarations are included](http://closure-compiler-debugger.appspot.com/#input0%3D%252F**%250A%2520*%2520%2540constructor%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Bstring%257D%2520bar%250A%2520*%2520%2540param%2520%257Bnumber%257D%2520barPrivate%250A%2520*%252F%250Avar%2520Foo%2520%253D%2520function(bar%252C%2520barPrivate)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257Bstring%257D%2520*%252F%250A%2520%2520this.bar%2520%253D%2520bar%253B%250A%2520%2520%252F**%2520%2540private%2520%257Bnumber%257D%2520*%252F%250A%2520%2520this.barPrivate_%2520%253D%2520barPrivate%253B%250A%257D%253B%250A%26input1%26conformanceConfig%26externs%26refasterjs-template%26includeDefaultExterns%3D1%26CHECK_SYMBOLS%3D1%26CHECK_TYPES%3D1%26CHECK_VISIBILITY%3D1%26CLOSURE_PASS%3D1%26LANG_IN_IS_ES6%3D1%26MISSING_PROPERTIES%3D1%26PRESERVE_TYPE_ANNOTATIONS%3D1%26PRETTY_PRINT%3D1%26TRANSPILE%3D1)... To me this means that visibility declarations are probably necessary but type declarations aren't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to run some tests to be certain but here is my understanding:

1. and 2. yes, the compiler knows `bar` is type `string` and `barPrivate` is type `number`.  <strike>But only for the duration of the constructor call.</strike>  It won't enforce that `this.bar` must only be a string in later code.
2. no, compiler will only enforce `@private` access when you provide the annotation as in your explicit example.

Some of these types of checks are more robust with the [new type inference (NTI)](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Using-NTI-(new-type-inference)) but perhaps not these specific cases.

Try to see what the compiler does with or without those annotations when you assign a different type to the property in another method (or later on in the constructor).

The same issue comes up with whether to specify types on a local variable in a method.

edit: As Chad Killingsworth points out, in this simple example the compiler can infer that `this.bar` is a string without additional annotation; but if some other type is assigned elsewhere to `this.bar` then "all bets are off", I don't know what the compiler would do then.

Comment: Yep, I think your understanding is correct based on the tests I've been running.  I was most interested in whether it would know the type of `this.bar` in other methods and based on my tests, the answer is a qualified "No" (qualified because the AST seems to still report the correct type, but the compiler doesn't emit the warnings that I would expect unless I explicitly spell out the type).  Adding the CHECK_TYPES_NEW_INTERFACE doesn't really seem to fix the problem either :-/.

Comment: The compiler should correctly infer that `this.bar` is a `string` in all cases - even outside of the constructor without additional annotation. `@private` would be needed though.